# Is it possible to move iOS 10 from Xcode 8 to Xcode 10 to be able to run on simulators with iOS 10 on Xcode 10 instead of download it from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 10 and I need to run my app in the simulator with iOS 10 for testing issue report. I'm asking if there is way to do it without downloading iOS 10 through Xcode as I have old version of Xcode 8.3.3 that supports iOS 10. I'm asking if it's possible to copy iOS 10 from Xcode 8 to Xcode 10. I can't use on Xcode 8.

Comment: Are you asking about the iOS 10 simulators? Xcode 10 supports iOS 10 without downloading anything so you must mean the iOS 10 simulators.

Comment: yes i mean iOS 10 simulators